# How to show all user purchased products in django-oscar?

Tags: python, django, django-oscar

I am trying to render all user purchased products on django-oscar and i am having some problems.

I can print all orders by user in order.order

```
OrderProduct.objects.filter(user=user)
```

but it doesn't print each product by itself if order include few products (which saved on order.line)
I can also print all products in orders.line

```
LineProduct.objects.all()
```

but i can't filter them by user since there is no user field in order.line.

I can add user field on order.line and copy from order each time order is placed but I don't think this is the best solution.

Anyone have any idea for a solution?

Thanks in advance

**Edit: this is the models file link**
https://github.com/django-oscar/django-oscar/blob/fe37a51c040303b6f0251d1973d39694c3eaba88/src/oscar/apps/order/abstract_models.py#L27

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can obtain a list of all the products purchased by a user with:

```
Product.objects.filter(line__order__user=user)
```

This is following the foreign key relatinship from `Line` to `Product` backwards, and then from `Line` to `Order` to `User` forwards (see [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/) for how this works).

This queryset is likely to result in duplicates, so you may want to add a `distinct()` clause at the end depending on what you want to do with it.

Answer (score 0):

In the django-oscar there is an Models  called "Lines", in django oscar there are two lines models :--

1. Line (items) of cart addition.
2. Line (items) of Order addition . ( so in order to get the purchased record you can go with Order line items ) have a direct relation with product model.